# How to debug #states mecanism - trying to get #states to work with inner fieldsets & webform

Tags: forms, webforms

I have a relatively simple webform, with 2 fieldsets and a few other fields. The fields aformentionned have #states  actions configured and behaving proper like in a regular form.

It is in the fieldset shown below I have a problem.
THe fieldset should be collapsed (via #states) and there is nothing I can do to make it so.

[image]

The offending fieldset has #states defined in the bottom form_alter, I outlined the error location in caps:

```
// Implements hook_form_alter()
function formHelper_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {            
switch ($form_id)  {

        case 'webform_client_form_1':

           // Set fieldsets as collapsible
          $form['submitted']['inscription']['#collapsible'] = true;
          $form['submitted']['inscription']['#collapsed'] = true;              

          $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_1']['#collapsible'] = true;
          $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_1']['#collapsed'] = false;

          $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_2']['#collapsible'] = true;
          $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_2']['#collapsed'] = true;             

            //vardump of fieldset
           dpm($form['submitted']);

           // Show datepicker for child one if inscription is part time
           $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_1']['jrs_semaine']['#states'] = array(
              'visible' => array(   // action to take.
                ':input[name="submitted[inscription][enfant_1][horaire]"]' =>
                  array('value' => 't_partiel'),
              ),   
           );
           // Show datepicker for child two if inscription is part time  
           $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_2']['jrs_semaine2']['#states'] = array(
              'visible' => array(   // action to take.
                ':input[name="submitted[inscription][enfant_2][horaire_2]"]' =>
                  array('value' => 't_partiel'),
              ),   
           );
            // THIS IS THE FIELDSETY THST DOES NOT WORK: 
           // set state on second fieldset to be visible only when two is seiected.       
           $form['submitted']['inscription']['enfant_2']['#states'] = array(
              'expand' => array(   // action to take.
                ':input[name="submitted[inscription][enfant_1][horaire]"]' =>
               array('value' => 't_partiel'),
              ),   
           );
          break;
 }
}
```

Now, in the drupal docs (example module) there is a fieldset shown  with working code using  as the state to change, and it seems in the docs fieldsets are clearly supported, alas not the one in my webform.

I am using the same condition that is working on the other field so I assume the problem is not with the selector. In light of this fact, I have no clue of what even to really look for but I really want to figure it out.

Is anyone familiar enough with #states to tell me how I could debug the js in this case?

I know it is in /misc/states.js, I just don't know what to look for in states.js, or even if this is what is preventing the fieldset from collapsing.

**update:** Reposted the full hook_form_alter function as per request.

Comment: input[name="submitted[inscription][nombre_denfants][horaire_2]"]"] looks strange: "] is duplicated

Comment: @Attiks yes thanks for catching that. All typos are fixed yet still #states is not firing for fieldsets. Will be looking into the JS side of this if I have the chance today, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the full code for both form items?

If the element needs to be collapsed at start-up you need to add '#collapsed' => TRUE,

It also looks like there's an error in you're selector as pointed out in comments

Comment: I added the settings to adjust the #collapsed tag as per your suggestion, but this still did not work out. I believe this same effect could also be done with simple jquery, since it is only a presentational change, but I would of liked to know  why #states was choking on this.

Comment: * Also, I added the whole form_alter, as you can see I used the same selector as I did in the 2 widgets.

Comment: It needs to be "expanded" not "expand"

Comment: yes I tried all, visible, expanded, neither has worked for this. I had this up and working in 5 mins. with JQuery instead, but will go back when time allows and trace why it was not working with #states.